# Drag and Drop Issue on a modal form

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I am opening an MDI Child form in my MDI container form and from that child form, I am opening another form as a modal for like this:

```
frmMyForm frm = new frmMyForm();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

This modal form has drag and drop ability to a DataGridView (ability to drag files from windows explorer and drop to the DataGridView).
now the problem is the drag and drop is working fine in my development pc but when I am transferring this to client machine it doesn't work, I see that the drag and drop events are not firing while it running on the client's machine.
Any Idea what the Problem is?

My Events are as bellow:

```
private void dgvDocuments_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    //e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    //MessageBox.Show("Drag Enter - " + e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)));

    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }
}

private void dgvDocuments_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        string[] strFiles = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    }
}

private void dgvDocuments_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // MessageBox.Show("Drag Over - " + e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)));
    if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
}
```

Also, I'd like to mention, I create a small app with one form with a dgv and drag and drop functionality to see if Drag and Drop works in this single form app. and it is working.

Comment: Drag events have only been available since .Net3.0 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.drageventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)
Has the target machine got the correct version of .Net installed?

Comment: Yes it does, Also I like to mention I create a small app with one form with a dgv to see if Drag and Drop is working in this single form app. and it is working fine.

Comment: The `DragOver` event is not useful for what it is doing now. You could just delete it. You might have some code there that selects the cell where the mouse pointer is dragged over; this can provide a visual aid for selecting the right cell target. Also, the expected `FileDrop` type has already been selected. The data type will be `System.String[]` (no matter how many files are being dragged).

Comment: I have tried to Panel also to form but the drag and drop still not working..

Comment: Do you run the app as administrator?

Comment: `typeof(System.String))`. This is not happening. A FileDrop `DataFormat` translates to `System.String[]` (**Array** of strings). Delete that event. It's more than useless as it is.

Comment: yes.. the app is running as administrator..

Comment: There is an issue when running with admin rights. Try without